# A question about complements in a group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I consider the property for a group $G$, that every time you take an element $g$ of prime order in $G$, then there is a complement $H$ to $\langle g\rangle$ in $G$ in the sense that $G=\langle g\rangle H$ and $\langle g\rangle\cap H=1$.

Let $G$ be the cartesian product (= unrestricted direct product) of infinitely many (say countable for simplicity) copies of $S_3$. It is very easy to show that $G$ satisfies this property.

I've read on some Russian paper that actually this property holds in all factor groups $G/N$ of $G$, but I'm unable to prove this.

I can reduce easily to the case in which $N\leq G'$ and $\langle gN\rangle\leq G'/N$ but I do not know how to go on from this. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think "cartesian product" is a word used mostly in Russian to mean "unrestricted direct product". I'm rather familiar to using "cartesian" to mean the setwise product, and "direct" referring to the choice of law (a semidirect product $A\ltimes B$ is another group law on the cartesian product $A\times B$).

Comment: What do you mean by "this property holds all factors groups"? the previous sentence does not refer to any quotient group. Maybe you mean the claim that every normal subgroup has a "complement"?

Comment: @YCor yes "cartesian product"="unrestricted direct product".
The sentence is: "For every cyclic subgroup of prime order there is a complement". This sentence should be satisfied in every factor group.

Comment: I've edited to clarify, feel free to revert if you don't like it. Also it would be helpful to provide the reference to the Russian paper.

Comment: Every factor group of which $G$? An arbitrary $G$ as in the first paragraph, or the more specific one in the second paragraph?

Comment: @verret second paragraph, but anyway this property is known (but I do not have a proof of it) to be inherited by factor groups of periodic groups satisfying it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true (I initially claimed the contrary): the case of elements of order $2$ is easy and the case of elements of order $3$ is a little more tricky.

Write $G=S_3^I$. Let $G_3=C_3^I$ be the 3-Sylow subgroup in $G$. Fix a 2-Sylow subgroup $C_2$ in $G_3$ and write $G_2=C_2^I$. We consider a quotient $Q=G/N$ of $G$.
Write $Q_3$ and $Q_2$ for the image of $G_3$ and $G_2$ in $Q$. Then $Q_p$ is elementary $p$-abelian, $Q=Q_2Q_3$ with $Q_3$ normal, and $Q_2\cap Q_3=\{1\}$. Hence $Q=Q_3\rtimes Q_2$.

(a) Suppose $c\in Q$ has order $2$; let $d$ be a lift of $c$ in $G$; then $d$ has order $2$ or $6$ and so up to replace $d$ with $d^3$, we can suppose that $d^2=1$; then up to conjugate in $G$, we can suppose that $d\in G_2$ and hence that $c\in Q_2$. Then it's clear that $\langle c\rangle$ has a normal complement (first mod out by $Q_3$ and boil down to the case of an elementary abelian 2-group).

(b) Let $\mathcal{T}$ be an [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(set_theory)) of subsets of $I$ (i.e., a set of subsets of $I$ with $\emptyset\in \mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}$ stable under taking finite unions, and intersections with subsets of $I$). Define $G_3(\mathcal{T})=\bigcup_{J\in \mathcal{T}}C_3^J$: this is a subgroup of $G_3=C_3^I$; moreover it is a $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^I$-submodule, i.e., it is stable under its obvious action switching the sign of coordinates, so that the corresponding semidirect product is $G$. If $\mathcal{T}$ is the complement of an [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) $\mathcal{U}$, then $G_3(\mathcal{T})$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $G_3=C_3^I\to C_3$ taking $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ to its $\mathcal{U}$-limit.

Conversely, it is easy to check that every $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^I$-submodule of $G_3$ has the form $G_3(\mathcal{T})$ for some ideal $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $I$. Indeed, the $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^I$-submodules of $G_3$ of index 3 are precisely the $G_3(\mathcal{T})$ for $\mathcal{T}$ the complement of some ultrafilter.

Now let $c\in Q$ have order $3$. Let $d\in G$ be a lift of $c$: then $d$ has order $3$ or $6$, and replacing $d$ with $d^4$ if necessary we can suppose that $d$ has order $3$. The support of $d$ is a nonempty subset $J$ of $I$. By the above, $N\cap G_3=G_3(\mathcal{T})$ for some ideal $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $I$ (so $J\notin \mathcal{T}$). Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a maximal ideal (of the Boolean algebra of subsets of $I$) such that $\mathcal{T}\subset \mathcal{M}$ and $J\notin \mathcal{M}$. (So the complement $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ is an ultrafilter.)

Then $d\notin G_3(\mathcal{M})N$. Indeed, we would have otherwise $d=gn$ in this decomposition, so $n=dg^{-1}\in N\cap G_3\subset G_3(\mathcal{M})$ and in turn $d\in G_3(\mathcal{M})$, a contradiction. Hence it is no restriction to assume that $N\cap G_3$ has index $3$ in $G_3$. Then the result follows from the following:

**Claim:** let $Q$ be a group with a normal subgroup $Q_3$ of order $3$ such that the quotient $Q/Q_3$ is elementary 2-abelian. Then $Q_3$ has a complement in $Q$.

Proof of the claim: let $A$ be the centralizer of $Q_3$. Then $A$ is characteristic in $Q$, and is the product of $Q_3$ with an elementary $2$-abelian subgroup $A_2$. Hence modding out by $A_2$, we can suppose that $Q_3$ equals its own centralizer. Then in this case $Q/Q_3$ acts faithfully on $Q_3$, so has order $1$ or $2$, so either $Q=Q_3$ and we're done, or $Q\simeq S_3$ and we're done too.